# How can I loop through a textfile but do something different on the first line, Python

Tags: python, loops, relation

I have a text file that looks something like this :

```
 original--                 expected output--
0 1 2 3 4 5              SET : {0,1,2,3,4,5}
1 3                      RELATION:{(1,3),(3,1),(5,4),(4,5)}
3 1 
5 4                      REFLEXIVE : NO
4 5                      SYMMETRIC : YES
```

and part of the code is having it print out the first line in curly braces, and the rest within one giant curly braces and each binary set in parentheses. I am still a beginner but I wanted to know if there is some way in python to make one loop that treats the first line differently than the rest?

Comment: did you try anything? How are you opening and iterating the file now? Do you know about `enumerate`?

Comment: Yes there are ways to do that. [ask]

Comment: Start the loop from the second line onwards

Comment: I am currently trying to pass the text file into readline() and gonna see if I use the [0] in its array to do something to loop through the first line and then a second loop to go through the other values

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this with filename is your file ..

```py
with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    set_firstline = []
    first_string = file.readline()
    list_of_first_string = list(first_string)
    for i in range(len(list_of_first_string)):
        if str(i) in first_string:
            set_firstline.append(i)
    
    print(set_firstline)
```

```bash
OUTPUT : [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

im new as well. so hope I can help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).